# How to make my table scrollable/responsive if it has many contents that don't fit my screen?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

I added an `overflow-x:scroll` to my panel because I have many columns in my table, which has worked nicely for scrolling. But the blue color of the panel heading stops at the right-hand side of the page; to the right after that the panel heading is white and it looks bad. How do I make the blue panel heading stretch to the right so it doesn't just cut off at the right hand side of the page?

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" style="overflow-x:scroll">
    <div class="panel-heading">Heading</div>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did my answer help you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Don't add inline styles like you did with `overflow-x: scroll`;
2. the solution to your problem is adding a `.table-responsive` div around your table.

From the [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive) :

> Create responsive tables by wrapping any .table in .table-responsive to make them scroll horizontally on small devices (under 768px). When viewing on anything larger than 768px wide, you will not see any difference in these tables.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">Heading</div>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how you get a table that scrolls nicely no matter how many rows / columns you have.